# css breadcrumbs breaks into 2 lines, how to controll it in responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, moodle, breadcrumbs

I have a list of breadcrumbs and it looks like this: [image]

but if there are too many steps or it is viewed on a device with lower resolution it's breaking and it gets ugly like this: [image]

My code is this:

```
ul.breadcrumb li { 
padding-left: 5px;
}
ul.breadcrumb li::after {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #959fa5;
}
ul.breadcrumb li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  width: 12px;
  background: url(/theme/base/pix/grey-white-grey2.png) no-repeat center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.breadcrumb li {
  background-color:@color-gery-background;
}
ul.breadcrumb li:nth-last-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: url(/theme/base/pix/grey-white-blue.png) no-repeat center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.breadcrumb li:last-child{
  background-color: @color-blue;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white!important;
}
ul.breadcrumb li:last-child a,
ul.breadcrumb li:last-child span
{
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white!important;
}
ul.breadcrumb li:last-child:after
 {
  content: ' ';
  height: 25px;
  width: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(/theme/base/pix/blue-whitey.png) no-repeat center center;
}
ul.breadcrumb li > *:last-child::before,
.cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li > *::before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 25px;
  width: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(/theme/base/pix/blue-whitey.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

And HTML

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">My home</a></li>
  <li><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

And since im working with moodle I don't have the posibillity to set more classes on the li´s and the content of the li is either a link or span with text only. (and not in any specific order)
Can I somehow make it so the last option is blur and not with images like now - I tried some other examples with bordering triangles but they were not responsiv either :-/

Comment: so..what do you want to do ? make all the breadcrumbs remain in 1 row ? without changing their styles ( font-size .width etc )

Comment: A fix could be that the 2nd last child were on the next line with the last child, when the screen is smaller so it doesn't break in the blue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do?

1. instead of using images for breadcrumbs, use **CSS**
2. **change CSS on small screen**, so that it will not look ugly.

like,

```
/* some breadcrumb basic code */

@media only screen and (max-width : 766px) {
    ... code for small devices ...
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 767px) {
    ... code for large devices ...
}
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfg6ku2y/3/) and try to resize the result window

[**This is updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zfg6ku2y/5/)

Comment: I have tried with the CSS triangles, that is around google, but I didn't work as expected. I had some serious trouble clearing the first child of lis going bad. Another problem with this is that, the text can be very long in each breadcrumb, so if I instead could control the breaking of the breadcrum

Comment: @HenrikSunePedersen have you checked the fiddle..? If not then please go through it. And try to resize the result window

Comment: _Yes I have seen the fiddle, and tried to rezise.
The problem is the same the "blue" can be broken into 2 lines.
http://screencast.com/t/5HFtaOMmlEfW

Comment: @HenrikSunePedersen Check the updated fiddle above. I think its working as you want. :-)   (and try to resize the result window)

Comment: Modyfied the script a little and its working - thanks a lot for the Help :-)